# Unity Custom Editor GUI

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, unity-editor

[image: screenshot]

I'm having an issue adding new values in fields after they are created in Editor, they keeping coming back and if i enter a new one it will display the first value. Can anyone give me snippet of code how can i add values which will be automatically saved.

Thanks!

```
    GUILayout.BeginHorizontal();
    GUILayout.BeginVertical();
    addInteger = GUILayout.Toggle(addInteger, "Integers");
    howMuchIntegers = EditorGUILayout.IntField(howMuchIntegers);
    intNames = new string[howMuchIntegers];
    if (addInteger)
    {
        if (howMuchIntegers != 0)
        {
            GUILayout.BeginVertical("box");
            for (int i = 0; i < howMuchIntegers; i++)
            {
                intNames[i] = i.ToString();
                intNames[i] = EditorGUILayout.TextField(intNames[i]);
            }
            GUILayout.BeginVertical("box");
        }
    }
    GUILayout.EndVertical();
    GUILayout.EndHorizontal();
```

Comment: What happens if you remove              intNames[i] = i.ToString();

Comment: Still won't alow me to update values it reverts them back to null as they are.

Comment: Second question. So you have this part intNames = new string[howMuchIntegers]; What happens if you remove this from the OnGui() section, and instead put it in just the class, or in the Start(). I think this part is getting called every update and is overwriting whatever you just saved.

Comment: That part works fine, look.
https://imgur.com/a/RtcfypJ

Comment: I want to type the values in those fields and to be saved in the array intNames[];

Comment: I will post an answer. If it doesn't work we can keep discussing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your data is getting overwritten in 2 places.

Here,

```
intNames = new string[howMuchIntegers];
```

and here,

```
intNames[i] = i.ToString();
```

So here is one solution. Basically I just suggest that you extract the parts that don't need to be run 60 times a second, you can do this however you want.

```
 bool firstTimeRun = true;

 void OnGUI()
 {    
    GUILayout.BeginHorizontal();
    GUILayout.BeginVertical();
    addInteger = GUILayout.Toggle(addInteger, "Integers");
    howMuchIntegers = EditorGUILayout.IntField(howMuchIntegers);

    if(firstTimeRun)
    {
        intNames = new string[howMuchIntegers];
        if (addInteger)
        {
            if (howMuchIntegers != 0)
            {
                GUILayout.BeginVertical("box");
                for (int i = 0; i < howMuchIntegers; i++)
                {
                    intNames[i] = i.ToString();
                    intNames[i] = EditorGUILayout.TextField(intNames[i]);
                }
                GUILayout.BeginVertical("box");
            }
        }

        firstTimeRun = false;
        GUILayout.EndVertical();
        GUILayout.EndHorizontal();
    }
    else
    {
        if (addInteger)
        {
            if (howMuchIntegers != 0)
            {
                GUILayout.BeginVertical("box");
                for (int i = 0; i < howMuchIntegers; i++)
                {
                    intNames[i] = EditorGUILayout.TextField(intNames[i]);
                }
                GUILayout.BeginVertical("box");
            }
        }
        GUILayout.EndVertical();
        GUILayout.EndHorizontal();
    }
 }
```

Comment: Glad I could help.

Comment: You saved me a lot of stress! ^_^